# How to install and run Grunt on Virtual Hosting?

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I have the problem with Grunt on Virtual Hosting without Admin right.
On my computer I install and run Grunt by the Command Prompt (open site directory by the "cd" press enter and then run commands like `npm install grunt ...`), but on the hosting there is an option named "Crontab" which makes same as Command Prompt, but "Crontab" has only one input field where will be typed the command and than system will run that.

So the question: How to open site directory and there run grunt command only by one line code?

Like `cd ~/my_site/public_html ; npm install` but this doesn't work (I tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the `grunt-cli` in local and run this local copy:

1) Install the grunt-cli locally : `npm install grunt-cli --save-dev`

2) Run the grunt cli (path can differ a little whether you're on Windows/Linux/Mac OS X) :

`./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt my-task`

This would be just like doing `grunt my-task` (but you're not using the global grunt-cli, but the local one, so no admin right needed).

Comment: I used Grunt on local host, but I thought that it's possible to do it on hosting.
I've just contacted to hosting support and they told me that there is no installed node.js on their server. So anyway thanks.